# cannot import the package aws-sdk on vue.js v3

Tags: vue.js, aws-sdk-js

I have a login.vue file (v3.11) to put ID information to User pool on AWS. But it cannot read `CognitoUserPool`. Installed version of aws-sdk is aws sdk 2.524.

I referred to the aws cognito docs. And what I wrote was as follows.

[Examples: Using the JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

- browser: chrome
- vue: v3.11
- aws sdk: 2.524

```
import { AmazonCognitoIdentity } from 'aws-sdk'

const userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(_this.authenticationData);
```

Error message:

> Login.vue?7463:121 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'CognitoUserPool' of undefined

Comment: Did you check poolData and _this.authenticationData? On what line in the code shown did you get an exception? Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cognito Identity SDK was moved to the [AWS Amplify package](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js), so you would need to install that instead of the AWS SDK for JavaScript.

There's a small note on about it on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html), but it's admittedly not very prominent:

> The [Amazon Cognito Identity SDK for JavaScript](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/) is now part of the [AWS Amplify Library](https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify).

After installing Amplify, should be able to create a new user pool like this:

```
import { CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
```